# Reading High & Low bits from bytes not working as expected in Java

Tags: java, android, byte, bit

I have a `major: 0` and `minor: 1517` version, which is encoded in bytes as follows: [5, -19]

Where upper 4 bits of first byte represents `major` version.

And lower 4 bits of first byte and second byte represents `minor` version.

Hex for the same is: `05ED`

**Below is my code that I am using to get the result:**

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {5, -19};
int major = data[0] >> 4 & 0x0F;
int minor = (((data[0] & 0x0F) << 8) | data[1]) & 0xFFFF_FFFF;
System.out.println("Major:" + major + ", Minor:" + minor);
```

**Expected Output**
`Major:0, Minor:1517`

**Actual Output**
`Major:0, Minor:-19`

I am unable to find what I am doing wrong here.

Can someone help me here?

**Note: Same thing iOS is working fine.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: `data[1]` -> `data[1] & 0xff`.

Comment: @saka1029 - Thanks, it's working.